# Trouble with ajax request response handler

Tags: javascript, ajax

Very new to ajax and trying to make an ajax request function to be reused. Firebug says the request is going through and returning the correct data from my php file. However, the response is not being inserted into the div in my html. here is my code:

```
function ajaxRequest(url, method, data, asynch, responseHandler)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url, asynch);

    if (method == "POST"){
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                responseHandler(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    request.send(data);
} 

function changeText() {
    var data = "";
    ajaxRequest("../PHP/CODE/changeText.php", "Get", data, true, insertNewText);
}

function insertNewText() {  
    var response = request.responseText;
    var testDiv = document.getElementById("rightColumn");
    testDiv.innerHTML = response;
}
```

Comment: did you `console.log(request)` on `request.status == 200` to see if you're getting anything back?

Comment: Aren't you getting errors in the Javascript console? The first line of `insertNewText()` is accessing an undefined variable `request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use insertNewText as a response handler.

Take a look at:

```
if (request.status == 200) {
    responseHandler(request.responseText);
}
```

in this block of code responseHandler is the function callback, in your context, this is insertNewText

as you can see in

```
responseHandler(request.responseText);
```

The responseText is passed to it

However in your insertNewText signature, you dont handle this

In conclusion:

```
function insertNewText() {  
    var response = request.responseText;
    var testDiv = document.getElementById("rightColumn");
    testDiv.innerHTML = response;
}
```

Should be :

```
function insertNewText(response) {  
    var testDiv = document.getElementById("rightColumn");
    testDiv.innerHTML = response;
}
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
function insertNewText() {  
   var response = request.responseText;
   var testDiv = document.getElementById("rightColumn");
   testDiv.innerHTML = response;
}
```

to

```
function insertNewText(html) {  
   var testDiv = document.getElementById("rightColumn");
   testDiv.innerHTML = html;
}
```